# Covariance between $Z$ and $Y$ where $Z=XY$

Tags: covariance, independence

What is: $${\rm Cov}(Z,X)$$ when $Z = XY$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

In essence, is the product of two independent variables independent of either one?

Comment: The product of two independent variables is independent of *neither*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you proceed by writing $\text{Cov}(XY,X)$ and use the rule $\text{Cov}(A,B) = E(AB)-E(A)E(B)$ then make use of the rule about expectations of products of independent variates, you can derive it exactly in very simple form (if the variables are not constant, the covariance is not zero if $E(Y)$ is not zero).

Here's why I wrote what I did in that last part in parentheses
(I am really hoping this isn't a self-study in disguise)

\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Cov}(Z,X) &=& \text{Cov}(XY,X)\\
&=& E(XY\cdot X) -E(XY)\cdot E(X) \\
&=& E(X^2Y) -E(X)^2E(Y) \\
&=& E(X^2)E(Y) -E(X)^2E(Y) \\
&=& E(Y)\text{Var}(X)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Are you sure about that last parenthetical remark?

Comment: @whuber well, there's always room for a mistake! I'll include my reason for saying so and you can help me spot the error.

Comment: I have now included the reason why I said that.

Comment: (+1) Sorry about the trouble--I was thinking of something else. The bilinarity of covariance immediately shows the answer is proportional to $E[Y]$.

Comment: No self-study. It was a problem in Financial Econometrics, where Y is as Chi-Squared distribution and X has some unknown form. This answer makes absolutely perfect sense, and the result seems very much correct. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @DanielB "A problem in Financial Econometrics" sounds pretty much *exactly* like what the `self-study` tag is defined to be about. Can you be more precise about the nature/origin of the problem?

Comment: I am writing a paper in Financial Econometrics about Realized Volatility and in my calculations I was confronted with the above problem originating from the asymptotic properties of my estimator. I'm sorry if I have used the wrong tags. It is my first question on here.

Comment: Okay, that's probably nearer to research than strictly self-study, even though the problem itself is relatively textbook-ish. So don't worry. However, I would advise that you pay attention to this part from the self-study guidelines in any case: *Be aware of school policy* (in this case in relation to seeking such help with your work). It's probably not a problem, but better to be sure